# Install modern browser on MacOs 10.4.11

Tags: macos, browser, desktop-computer, imac, software-update

I want to use an **old iMac on MacOsX 10.4.11 as my office pc**.
I mainly **need a modern webbrowser**.

Is there any chance that i can **install a new browser** on MacOsX 10.4.11?
Or can i even **update MacOs**? Autoupdate says no updates.

Edit:
The mac has a CoreDuo

Comment: What browsers have you tried to install?

Comment: Firefox stable and Firefox esr

Comment: And those don’t work, or they don’t meet your definition of a modern browser? FF Stable seems like that would be considered modern.

Comment: They dont work. A message appears and says the computer doesnt meet the requirements.

Comment: It is an iMac4,1

Answer (score 1):

Autoupdate will only up*date* the current system (e.g. 10.4.0 -> 10.4.11), not up*grade* it (e.g. 10.4.x -> 10.5.x). Whether you can upgrade depends on the hardware model; you can look it up at [everymac.com](https://everymac.com) (look for the "Maximum MacOS" statistic).

If you *can* run a newer version of Mac OS X, getting an installer disc may be tricky. For example, if you can run 10.5 Leopard, archive.org has [several Leopard Install DVD images](https://archive.org/search.php?query=os%20x%20leopard). 9A343 is a beta-test build, so you don't want that, but there seem to be two drop-in DVD images (part #2Z691-6040-A) which IIRC is what Apple "dropped into" computers that had been manufactured but not sold when 10.5 came out, so it should work. You'll need to burn it to a DVD-R, then boot from that to do the installation. Then download & install the [10.5.8 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL866) and then [security update 2012-003](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1533).

As for a browser: if you have a PPC Mac, you could run [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) (although development is in the process of ending).

Comment: I have an Intel iMac, is there a secure browser for these old Mac OS X versions?

Comment: @AiCaffeaffe I don't know of any particularly good browsers for old Intel Macs. I think you can run TenFourFox under Rosetta, but I don't know how well it'll perform. There's also [FireFox Legacy](https://parrotgeek.com/fxlegacy.html), but I haven't used it and it looks rather out-of-date. BTW, 10.6 was the last version that supported Rosetta, so if you need that you shouldn't upgrade past 10.6.

Comment: so the image is bigger than 4.7 gb. Can i also install via usb?

Comment: @AiCaffeaffe I *think* so, but I haven't tested it. You'll probably need to use Disk Utility's Restore feature to copy it to a USB drive. (BTW, the official "correct" option is to use a dual-layer DVD-R.) (Well, technically, that's not correct either, since you aren't really supposed to make your own install media.)